# AndEngine TimerHandler - onTimePassed

Tags: timer, andengine

I am using AndEngine to create Physics Simulations of projectiles being launched. As it simulates, I want to draw the parable's track.
To do so, I am drawing a square every second according to the position of the projectile(sPlayer).

```
time_handler=new TimerHandler(1, true,  new ITimerCallback() {


@Override
public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {

    if(simulationOn){ // every 1 second if the simulation is on
        int px=(int)sPlayer.getSceneCenterCoordinates()[0];
        int py=(int)sPlayer.getSceneCenterCoordinates()[1];
        parabola_point=new Rectangle(px, py,4, 4,getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        parabola_point.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        if(!highest_point_found){ //if highest point not found, check it
            float difY =  (float) Math.floor(Math.abs(body.getLinearVelocity().y)) ;

            if(Float.compare(0f, difY) == 0){ // if it is the highest point
                highest_point_found=true;
                drawPointText(); //draw the positions on the scene
                parabola_point=new Rectangle(px, py,16, 16,getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                parabola_point.setColor(Color.RED); // paint this point red


            }
        }


        parabola.add(parabola_point);
        scene.attachChild(parabola_point);
    }



     //  pTimerHandler.reset();

    }
});
```

I am using a FixedStepEngine:

```
  @Override
public Engine onCreateEngine(final EngineOptions pEngineOptions) {
return new FixedStepEngine(pEngineOptions, 50);
}
```

THE PROBLEM IS:

I don't know **why onTimePassed is being called faster than 1 second interval**.It happens after some seconds.

I read that **problaby the FixedStepEngine is changing the interval that 'onTimePassed' is called. How to fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are not unregistering your timer handlers which causes them to intersect with one another. Try unregistering pTimerHandler

Comment: You are right, I was missing registering it multiple times in a part of the code.Is there some method to check if it is already registered? Thanx.

Comment: I guess the best way around this is to always unregister within the onTimePassed method so you will avoid timers intersecting each other. I'm not quite sure though if there is a method that returns a boolean according to its state (registered or not).